# Expected sum of largest 3

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I pick 4 numbers from the Uniform Distribution.  I need the expected value of the sum of the 3 largest. I am pretty sure that the answer is 9 / 5 which agrees with a simulation. I would like to get mathematica to do this. I have tried this:

```
Assuming[a >= b >= c >= d, 
  Expectation[a + b + c, {a, b, c, d} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1},{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]]
```

which returns 3 / 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi; There is backslash "\" in front of [Distributed].

Comment: I am not good in probability at all. But isn't expectation a linear operation? So E[a+b+c]=E[a]+E[b]+E[c], and since E[*]=1/2 since it is Uniform{0,1}, and no drawing was biased in any way, then the result is 1.5, why would it be 1.8 as you say?

Comment: Hi Nasser; It is because you are not just picking 3 numbers randomly from that distribution, you are picking 4 and choosing to add the 3 largest of the 4. This skews it above the mean since the smallest value is never used.

Comment: If you format your question according to the [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) backslashes won't disappear.

Comment: Hi; Thanks for editing it. In the future I will try to do a better job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could compute the expectation of `a + b + c + d - Min[a, b, c, d]`:

```
Expectation[a + b + c + d - Min[a, b, c, d],
 {a, b, c, d} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]

(* 9/5 *)
```

Or you could use [`OrderDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OrderDistribution.html)

```
With[{f = OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], 4}, #] &},
 Expectation[a + b + c, 
   {a \[Distributed] f[4], b \[Distributed] f[3], c \[Distributed] f[2]}]]

(* 9/5 *)
```

Comment: Hi; I knew about the idea of using the minimum, I was hoping for an order statistic solution just like the one you and rasher provided. Thanks much.

Comment: Umm -- the solution given here using `OrderDistribution` is correct by chance, but the approach is not actually valid. In particular, it defines `a` as the distribution of the largest order statistic, `b` as the second largest ... etc ... each univariate ... BUT what is actually needed is the joint pdf of $(a,b,c)$ ... not the marginal pdfs of `a`, `b` and `c`. The solution happens to work in this particular instance, not because the method is correct, but because $E[a + b + c] = E[a] + E[b] + E[c]$. By contrast, the proposed method would give the wrong answer for: `Expectation[a b c, etc]`

Answer (score 9):

Here's what you want:

```
Expectation[
  x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, {x1, x2, x3, x4} \[Distributed] 
   ProductDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], 4}]] - 
 Expectation[x, 
  x \[Distributed] OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], 4}, 1]]

(* 9/5 *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way to use `OrderDistribution`: use the joint distribution of largest three order statistics in a sample of size four:

```
dist = OrderDistribution[{UniformDistribution[], 4}, {2, 3, 4}];
Expectation[x + y + z, {x, y, z} \[Distributed] dist]
(* 9/5 *)
```